# Iterating a nested array doesn't display data from all arrays

Tags: php

I have this array i am getting from mongodb in php

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => 
            [singleBed] => 6
            [doublebed] => 5
            [largeBed] => 5
            [extraLargeBed] => 4
            [bunkBed] => 4
            [sofaBed] => 5
            [futonMat] => 4
            [roomTypes] => apartment
            [bathroomType] => private
            [numberofRoomsofThisType] => 77
            [room_name] => KIng Room
            [price_per_night] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => 
            [singleBed] => 8
            [doublebed] => 7
            [largeBed] => 9
            [extraLargeBed] => 6
            [bunkBed] => 4
            [sofaBed] => 4
            [futonMat] => 2
            [roomTypes] => family
            [bathroomType] => private
            [numberofRoomsofThisType] => 77
            [room_name] => Queen Room Deluxe
            [price_per_night] => 0
        )

)
```

When i use this code

```
foreach (array($rows['property_setup']) as $key => $value) {
    //print_r($value['stayRooms']);
    foreach (array($value['stayRooms']) as $k => $v) {
        print_r($v);
        //echo $v[$k]['sofaBed'];
    }

}
```

this code `print_r($value['stayRooms']);` and this code `print_r($v);` display the same array as shown above and this `echo $v[$k]['sofaBed'];` only displays value 5 from array at index `0`

How can i display data from array at index `0` and `1`?

**Update**

```
Array
(
    [stayRooms] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 
                    [singleBed] => 6
                    [doublebed] => 5
                    [largeBed] => 5
                    [extraLargeBed] => 4
                    [bunkBed] => 4
                    [sofaBed] => 5
                    [futonMat] => 4
                    [roomTypes] => apartment
                    [bathroomType] => private
                    [numberofRoomsofThisType] => 77
                    [room_name] => KIng Room
                    [price_per_night] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 
                    [singleBed] => 8
                    [doublebed] => 7
                    [largeBed] => 9
                    [extraLargeBed] => 6
                    [bunkBed] => 4
                    [sofaBed] => 4
                    [futonMat] => 2
                    [roomTypes] => family
                    [bathroomType] => private
                    [numberofRoomsofThisType] => 77
                    [room_name] => Queen Room Deluxe
                    [price_per_night] => 0
                )

        )

    [numberOfGuests] => 33
    [apartmentsSize] => 5
    [numberOfBathrooms] => 44
    [numberOfLivingRooms] => 33
    [numberOfSofaBeds] => 76
    [otherSingleBed] => 3
    [otherDoublebed] => 4
    [otherLargeBed] => 2
    [otherExtraLargeBed] => 7
    [otherBunkBed] => 9
    [otherSofaBed] => 6
    [otherFutonMat] => 6
    [userid] => 60d3a4a9cb50d874614d67d3
    [recordid] => 662626277272
)
```

The code to produce the array above

```
foreach (array($rows['property_setup']) as $key => $value) {
        print_r($value);
        foreach (array($value['stayRooms']) as $k => $v) {
            //print_r($v);
            //echo $v[$k]['sofaBed'];
        }
    //echo $v[$k]['sofaBed'];
    }
```

Comment: Need to show more of your array, there is no `property_setup` or `stayRooms`.

Comment: And you're creating a new dimension with a  element array with the `array(` in the `foreaach`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver See the update

Comment: Its necessary to have that array.

Answer (score 0):

By using the wrapping `array()` when you loop through the data, you are creating an array with the contents being the data you're trying to loop through.

```php
<?php

$rows = [
  [
      'value1' => 'asdf',
      'value2' => 'asdfasdf',
      'value3' => 'asdfasdfasdf',
  ],
  [
      'value1' => 'qwerty',
      'value2' => 'qwertyqwerty',
      'value3' => 'qwertyqwertyqwerty'
  ],
];

foreach ($rows as $index => $cols) {
    foreach ($cols as $key => $value) {
        echo "Row: $index, key: $key : $value" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

```
Row: 0, key: value1 : asdf
Row: 0, key: value2 : asdfasdf
Row: 0, key: value3 : asdfasdfasdf
Row: 1, key: value1 : qwerty
Row: 1, key: value2 : qwertyqwerty
Row: 1, key: value3 : qwertyqwertyqwerty
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it this way

```
foreach (array($rows['property_setup']) as $key => $value) {
    //print_r($value);
    foreach (array($value['stayRooms']) as $k => $v) {
        //print_r($v);
        $count = (int)count($v);
        //echo $count;
        $index = $count - 1;
        for ($x = 0; $x <= $index; $x++) {
        echo "Array $index : ->>>".$v[$x]['sofaBed'].'<br/>';
        }
    }
}
```